# What is the equivalent of Excel's Subtotal in Power Pivot?

Tags: powerpivot, powerview

Is there a way to count the total number of rows returned in a filtered table in Power Pivot? I tried populating a column with 1 or 0 and used SUM. But it returned the number of rows in the original table and not in the filtered.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count rows, you can use this formula

```
Myformula:=Countrows(mytable)
```

Comment: Hello, i would like to count the rows that are visible with my current filter. Countrows(mytable) returns all the rows including those that are filtered.

Comment: Have you add this formula as a calculated column or as measure? Can you upload the excel file?

Comment: I made a new post that has an image uploaded. Sorry I can't upload the file because it is confidential. Please take a look at this post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011091/is-there-a-way-to-populate-a-column-with-scalar-value-in-power-pivot 
Thank you for your time.